# Why can I no longer open the Security & Privacy pane of System Preferences?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, security, preferences, privacy

## Problem

Since April 2012, one user of my MacBook Pro can no longer load the Security & Privacy pane.

When I click the icon, a sheet drops down:

[image]

Translated from Chinese to English:

> **Error**
>
> Cannot load System Preferences pane "Security & Privacy".

This is chaotic for me. Please: what has happened, and how can I fix it?

I also posted to Apple Support Communities:

- [Security & Privacy System Preferences pane cannot open!](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3842686)

### Environment

Lion, Mac OS X 10.7 -> 10.7.1 -> 10.7.2 -> 10.7.3 (Build 11D50b).

I setup two users:

- *zoomq* — my own account
- *wan* — my wife's  account, not often used by her
- zh-CN ([PRC Chinese](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/I18N__LangTags__List5.8.9.3pm.html)) ([Mainland China, simplified characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation)) preferred for both users
- both are administrators
- install/uninstall software is all standard steps.

### Troubleshooting

User *zoomq* can not load the pane.

Switch users, *wan* can open the pane without problem.

All other preference panes open and work fine.

When the problem occurs, nothing is logged. I have tried `tail -f` and all kinds of /var/log .log files.

I have not touched many system files.

I try remove
/Users/zoomq/Library/Preferences/com.apple.se*

```
com.apple.security.plist
com.apple.security.revocation.plist
com.apple.security.revocation.plist.lockfile
```

and rebooted, nothing changed.

```
$ ls /Library/Preferences/com.apple.se*
com.apple.security.appsandbox.plist
com.apple.security.plist
com.apple.security.systemidentities.plist
com.apple.servermgrd.plist
```

For *wan*, ~/Library/Preferences/
com.apple.security.* files are not present.

Comment: For the user where the preference pane does load: is the preferred (uppermost) language the same as your preferred language?

Comment: Which language do you prefer when the sheet in your screenshot drops down? Since you last loaded the pane, has any new or updated software been installed?

Comment: all is Chinese cn_zh
- i setup 2 user: zoomq , wan
- all as administrator
- now, "zoomq" can not load "Security & Privacy " preference pane
- "wan" is my wife's  account, but she not often usage

so this make chaos for me...
- what happen?
- i not touch many sys. files...
- install/uninstall software is all std. steps

Comment: Was the problem noticeable before the update to Mac OS X 10.7.3? From which version did you update: 10.7, 10.7.1 or 10.7.2? Which build is your installation of 10.7.3: 11D50, 11D50a, 11D50b, 11D50c or 11D50d?

Comment: When your wife's account *wan* is used without problem, is it a fast user switch, or does *zoomq* log out before *wan* logs in? wan's view of the parental controls pane should not list administrator zoomq. Does that pane appear proper to wan?

Comment: update auto from 10.7 -> 10.7.3, now is Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D50b)

Comment: Thanks. Hint: as we improve the opening question, you may wish to either (a) remove some of these comments; or (b) accept the invitation to automatically move discussion to Ask Different Chat.

Comment: zoomq logout,and usage "wan" is all ok,all noe opened parental option. just setup "wan" as administrator

Comment: when upgread, all is auto. and cleanning,and good,not any alert, 10.7->10.7.1->10.7.2->10.7.3

Comment: What response to the following command? Please add the result to the opening question … `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences | grep ecur`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try applying a combo update

You might try:

1. download the most recent MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.3.dmg
2. log in as *zoomq*
3. prefer British English or British
4. install the combination update
5. restart the computer, you should find 11D50d or greater
6. run Software Update until all other updates are installed
7. prefer Chinese (simplified)
8. quit System Preferences
9. reopen System Preferences, retry the preference pane.

### Background

At [OS X Lion Update 10.7.3 (Client Combo)](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484) there is no hint that Apple published different downloads with identical names. Differences between 11D50b, 11D50c and 11D50d are not published by Apple. This situation surrounding 10.7.3 is most unusual.

Generally, without focus on 10.7.3: in some problem situations, people find that installation or re-installation using a combo has a positive effect.

In this case: the *b* in your current installation, *11D50b*, probably indicates that a combo (combination) update has been applied once already — maybe through the Software Update routines that are integral to OS X. Reapplying the same update, or a more recent build of the same update, should do no harm.

There may be more technical ways of investigating causes of your problem. However: because the symptoms are unusual, I am inclined to suggest a combo update before anything else.

Comment: thanx sooo much! only one question:

how to usage "Client Combo" upgrade OS?
just like norm. software install?
open as finder, `cmd+o` and flow steps?

Comment: Download and open the .dmg then open MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.3.pkg and follow the on-screen advice. Use Installer.app as you normally would.

Comment: thanx! downloding 1.24Gb ... 150Kb/s,i'm chinese,in China,,,the net is soooooooo slow ;-(

Comment: sooo sorry ,try later, flow u suggest,upgrade,into Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D50d), when language as en,is all ok,but, when i change language as Chinese, problem is same,not any changed... ;-(